# How can I make phone call in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How can I make a phone call in Objective-C?

Comment: If you're talking about VOIP, try the PJSIP library (http://www.pjsip.org/).

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You can initiate a call

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html

So this would probably work:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:12125551212"]  options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, but in the iphone simulator nothing happened. just like forze. SHouldn't the application close and the phone starts dialing?

Comment: The simulator doesn't have a phone.  Check it on the device.

Comment: I believe you now need to do @"tel://5555555555". Mine didn't work without the forward slashes.

Comment: i want to call the emergency SOS number when app is in background , does anyone know how can i do it ?

Answer (score 24):

This is clipped from a project I did to do just that:

```
NSString *phoneStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phone_number];
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneStr];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
```

Comment: Please use autorelease unless you've got some reason not to. Also you can use `stringWithFormat` which already gives you an autoreleased object.

Comment: @Yar - Actually, please avoid autorelease unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: @Abizern, why? You worried about the memory or performance overhead? Until we get ARC (which we're already getting on iOS) or a gc (like on MacOS), autorelease makes code much cleaner with almost no overhead. Unless you're in a long loop, I (and many other people, I can cite that if you'd like) believe that autorelease is preferable.

Comment: From guru Vincent Gable's blog: http://vgable.com/blog/2010/05/19/n-a-r-c/ ... NARC has been picked up pretty widely on SO, and using autorelease will keep you sane.

Answer (score 19):

It may also be helpful to know how to prompt the user to call a number:

```c
NSURL *phoneNumber = [NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://13232222222"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneNumber];
```

`telprompt` gives the user a choice to place the call or cancel making the call before the phone dials. The two forward slashes after the colon are optional.

Comment: How did you find this? It's currently [undocumented](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=telprompt). Also, is there any difference with `tel`? Both seem to prompt anyway.

Answer (score 11):

well if you are talking about using objective-c to make a phone call on the iphone, then you can do something like this:

```
NSURL *phoneNumber = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"tel:867-5309"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: phoneNumber];
```

If you are talking about doing this on a mac ,well, then like others have mentioned that is specific based on number of things like, if you are using voip, a modem, connecting through something like an Asterisks box, etc..

Answer (score 5):

openURL is deprecated.

Now use this:

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[application openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"tel:12125551212"] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

**REMOVE EMPTY SPACES IN PHONE NUMBER**

```
NSString *phoneNumberString = @"123 456";
phoneNumberString = [phoneNumberString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
phoneNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat@"tel:%@", phoneNumberString];
NSURL *phoneNumberURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumberString]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneNumberURL];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"Phone number here";
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:numberString];        
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
[webView loadRequest:requestURL];
```

Answer (score -2):

This will either be very platform-specific, or you'll have to use a wrapper library to account for the differences among platforms, so you better state what platform this is intended for. In general, there are various telephony APIs available on most platforms.

On Windows systems there's for example the "TAPI", also things may somewhat differ if you are targeting a digital telephone system such as ISDN, because there are other APIs available.

Comment: The question did specify Objective-C though, which in this case _probably_ means iOS