# How to call a number on a button click in iphone development

Tags: iphone

I am trying to create an application in which I want to call a specific number on button click...
Button is having a title "Call xxx-yyy-zzzz for help", after clicking this button call menu will appear with this number dialed and I can either place a call or reject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
    openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://xxx-yyy-zzzz"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) how to initiate a call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:yourtelephonenumber"]];
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665769/how-to-make-phone-call-by-using-objective-c) also has some answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIAlertView to implement this, code as follows,

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction
{
   UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Call xxx-yyy-zzzz?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES",nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

//AlertView delegate

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
 if(buttonIndex==1)
   {
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
    openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://xxx-yyy-zzzz"]];   
   }
   else
   {
    //Do whatever you want
   }
}
```