# How to make a call in iphone?

Tags: iphone, call

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to make phone call by using objective c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665769/how-to-make-phone-call-by-using-objective-c)

I am trying to make a call when I click on the tableview row.

But it is not working.

Here is the code snippiest.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"1800-000-000"]];
}
}
```

I don't know why it is not working.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: if ([indexPath row] == 0)  , may also be the reason of problem. and also the "1800-000-000" should be @"tel:1800-000-000" .

Comment: @Hadley i have added "tel:1800-000-000", but still it is not working. It is possible to test in simulator r else i need to connect to device.

Comment: @Sachi , obviously , you should not test on simulator , you must test on device.

Comment: @Sachi , your code says , by tapping first row only you will be able to call . Pay attention towards your IF statement

Comment: @Hadley Thank you very much. It's working fine. One more thing i need to ask do you know about OCR.

Comment: @sachi , did you mean Optical character Recognition ? , image to text  ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this link I think it will help you
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html

this ll work try this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:12125551212"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

add tel: protocol

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1800-000-000"]];
}
}
```

Comment: just i have added tel: protocol. But still it's not working. Do i need to give any permission as in android. @Rahul Choudhary

Comment: @sachi There is no permission system in iOS. The above thing should work, try removing '-' from the number and see.

Comment: No still it's not working. Do we require a device for testing this. Because i am testing in simulator. I am new to iphone development.

Comment: The simulator can't make phone calls, so `tel:` URLs do nothing. Test on a device.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
    NSString *aPhoneNo = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:[itsPhoneNoArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]] ;
    NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:aPhoneNo];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

I think it will help you

Answer (score 1):

```
+ (void)openPhone:(NSString *)number {
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", number];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
}
```

Use this and like it.