# Directly launch phoneNumber dialog on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

If I use the UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber on a UITextView, and click a phone number on a device that has no phone (e.g. iPad), I get a Send Message / Add to Contacts / Copy popover.  Is there some way to bring up that dialog directly in code or would I have to reimplement?

I did try  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:5555555"]]; but that does not bring up the dialog.

There are some subtle differences between how detected links and buttons behave and my client wants a clickable phone number that behaves like a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some method swizzling to see where this popover comes from, and it looks like it is generated before the openURL: method in UIApplication.

Digging further, it looks like the popover comes from some private objects in UITextView.

I think you'll have to reimplement.

[image: attached backtrace]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it with some forward slashes?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://5555555"]];
```

Possibly related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/665808/1431813).

Comment: I hadn't thought of that - just tried, but doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Maybe try using an intent.
`String url = "tel:3334444";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);`

Comment: @agressen Intents don't exist on iOS :)

Comment: Whoops. That's my bad. For some reason when I came back to this question I assumed OP was using Android.

Answer (score 0):

Use `telprompt://5555555` instead of `tel:5555555`

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the suggestion, didn't seem to work. Here's my code   (IBAction)doit:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://5555555"]];
}

Comment: You're using this on a device, not the simulator?

Comment: And are you positive the action is correctly connected?  Put a breakpoint in it and make sure you hit the breakpoint.

Comment: Yes I did confirm the method was being called (with breakpoints and logging) and tested on device - though the simulator (iPad, ios7) also pops the dialog in question with a data detector.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you then, it's working fine for me.  Not overriding openURL are you :)

Comment: David, probably we're misunderstanding each other or else xcode just really likes you better.  here's a demo project that shows what I'm talking about.  I want the doit button to act like the phone number link.  https://github.com/somerset/PhoneNumberDataDetector

Comment: Sorry, I missed the whole iPad thing.  Yeah, you'll have to implement that popover by hand as far as I know.